# How to avoid async event handlers order messed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await

I struggle to find a way of having a guarantee that I have the right data after some async functions are called.
I have a list of elements with an async onclick handler for each element. I have a slider which opens when an element is clicked and is populated asynchronously with some data.

```
const onClickElement = async () => {
    // open slider
    // await fetch data to display 
}
```

On slider close I have some async functionality to delete the data from the slider.

```
const onSliderClose = aync () => {
   // await async clear data 1
   // await async clear data 2
}
```

If I click close slider and immediately after, I click another element to reopen the slider,the new data is fetched before the slider onSliderClose handler finishes. The on close slider functionality resumes and is clearing all the previoualy fetched data.
I am using react and redux for data storing.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are just clearing the data that is already in the slider you can do that synchronously.

Comment: You could set a state indicating that the `onSliderClose` function is finished. And only when that state is, for example, `true` then new data can be fetched. Though why does the `onSliderClose` have to be async?

Comment: Can you post the actual code please, not just pseudo code with comments? It's not clear why clearing the data from the slider is asynchronous (or, why it is required at all).

Comment: The async actions on close slider will patch unsaved changes on the element and fetch the up to date list and after all clears the redux store of the element that was displayed inside the slider. But as the onClickElement and onCloseSlider happen to write the same place in store, I end up sometimes with having the element undefined from store because the order is not guaranteed

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "patch" or what kind of changes a "slider" holds, but still you should be able to synchronously read the values, synchronously clear the DOM, synchronously hide the element, and then do your asynchronous patching operations. Again, please [edit] your question to include the actual code.

Comment: By patch I mean an async call to update changed properties on the opened element.The way it happens(not always) is:  1. Do first async action from on close 2. Get new element data to be saved in store 3. Do the second asymc action from  on close slider and clear the store -> not the data I exepect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Use await with async!

```
const onClickElement = async () => {
    // open slider
    // fetch data to display 
await fetchData()
}
```

Or alternative

```
const onClickElement = async () => {
        // open slider
        // fetch data to display 

    }

    onClickElement.then( () => {
    //Do what you have to do here
    })
```

Comment: I already use await when fetching data, doesnt help. I edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: `onClickElement.then(…)` will cause an exception